# Vue Module parse failed: Unexpected token "??" (Nullish coalescing operator)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, primevue

I recently updated the PrimeVue version of my project to latest (3.26.1) and now I'm getting the following error when running **npm run dev**:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                10:32:46 AM
error  in ./node_modules/primevue/virtualscroller/virtualscroller.esm.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (635:39)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         },
|         getPageByFirst(first) {
>             return Math.floor(((first ?? this.first) + this.d_numToleratedItems *4) / (this.step || 1));
|         },
|         isPageChanged(first) {

@ ./src/main.ts 48:0-55 73:631-646
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.11:8081&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
```

I figured out that the problem is the nullish coalesscing operator in line 635 of virtualscroller.esm.js file, as it is shown in the logs above.

I tried adding the following plugin to my **babel.config.js** file, but nothing changed:

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"]
}
```

I'm totally ignorant about webpack and/or babel in depth configurations, so I'm lost here and have no idea where to search for.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Edit 1:

I tried adding transpileDependencies in my **vue.config.ts** file, but with no success either.

My vue.config.ts file:

```
export default {
    devServer: {
        port: process.env.VUE_APP_PORT || 8081,
        proxy: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT || 'http://localhost:8080/',
        https: true
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            libraryExport: 'default',
            resolve: {
                symlinks: false
            }
        }
    },
    transpileDependencies: ['primevue']
}
```

Edit 2: **My webpack setup is VUE CLI**

Comment: It's unknown what's your webpack setup. If it's Vue CLI, this should be explicitly stated. The problem is that /node_modules/primevue/ deps should be processed by Babel, with Vue CLI this would be solved with transpileDependencies option

Comment: Yeah, it is VUE CLI. I just recently stumbled on this feature transpileDependencies. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Do you know exactly where should I put this property?

Comment: To vue.config.js, there's a lot of examples of its usage on SO

Comment: I added the code snippet of my vue.config.ts file. I don't know if I placed 'transpileDependencies' in the correct place. Would you mind giving a look at it? I've only found examples with vue.config.js files, not .ts.

Comment: There's no difference in this case. You need to transpile `primevue`, not `@primevue/virtualscroller`. It's /node_modules/primevue/ that you see in the error

Comment: I changed to `primevue` but the error persists :/

Comment: Not sure what's going one at this point, I'd expect it to work. Consider providing a way to reproduce the problem. You likely wouldn't have this problem with up-to-date Vue CLI

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently using VUE CLI 4 in this project. I'll try upgrading it to the newest one.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and just upgraded my Vue CLI. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by upgrading Vue CLI 4 to Vue CLI 5.

Just needed to ran `vue upgrade` command, select 'yes' where it was asked and all my problems with webpack/babel loaders were gone.